# Disable Jupyter Notebook cell search

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook

I want to disable cell search in Jupyter notebooks:

[image]

It's bound to `cmd + f` so I find it super annoying as most browsers have excellent built-in search. I looked through "Help -> Edit keyboard shortcuts" but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is pressing `Ctrl(Cmd)+F` twice; The first try will open Jupyter's search box and the second one will switch to Browser's search box.

If your prefered interface is classic notebook, there's a Keyboard shortcut editor extension that lets you add, edit, or remove keyboard shortcuts. But there is limitations in it.

Ex:

- Some combinations may not be identified by jupyter at all
- The editor won't accept anything with a comma in it
- You're not allowed to add conflicting shortcuts **(What you're looking for)**

In the JupyterLab you can edit features as simple as possible. Go to `Settings -> Advanced Settings Editor -> Keyboard Shortcuts`. in the list of commands you can find documentsearch options.

To disable default search shortcut, copy the `documentsearch:start` command into the User Preferences window and then add `"disabled": true` to it as below and then save it.

```
{
    "shortcuts": [
        {
            "command": "documentsearch:start",
            "keys": [
                "Accel F"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-mod-searchable",
            "disabled": true
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above command, Accel corresponds to `Cmd` on Mac and `Ctrl` on Windows.

After relaunching Jupyter you can access browser search box by pressing `Ctrl(Cmd)+F`.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.

Comment: Adding the above now opens another search right on the cell :( I hate when there is no simple "delete". I don't understand how anyone can think this feature is useful if there is search built into the browser working perfectly fine.